# Shock formation in nonlinear transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

The solution implies that $u_0(0-)$ is equal to $\alpha$
. However the question states that $u_0(x)=\alpha$ for  $x>0$. Wouldn't $u_0(0-)$ be equal to the "smooth function for $x<0$"? I have underlined the relevant parts in orange.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Think of the purpose of the example: to show shock *formation*. Shock is a discontinuity of velocity $u$. So to demonstrate how it *forms*, we should begin with continuous velocity field; otherwise the shock is already there at time $0$, and we just study its *propagation*.

Yes, the authors consider that "smooth function for $x<0$" is has limit $\alpha$ as $x\to 0-$, which makes the function $u_0$ continuous. They neglected to state this explicitly, but I think the intent is clear. In the first sentence, I would replace "piecewise continuous" by "piecewise smooth".